# MySQL Navicat Lite - ошибка соединения

Tags: mysql

Начинаю изучать MySQL. При попытке соединения выдаёт ошибку: 2003 - Can't connect MySQL server on 'localhost'
Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, каким образом программа Navicat (и другие ей подобные) при указания только лишь порта соединения (localhost - port 3306) ищуть базу MySQL на компе. MySQL устанавливал так, просто скачал архив с официального сайта и разархиваровал на D:\

Comment: перезагрузи комп, что ли, localhost - это 127.0.0.1

Comment: Надо было просто запустить в папке bin mysqld.exe и mysql.exe

Answer (score 1):

если на офсайте, то там исходники в архивах. Вам нужен [инсталлер](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/5.6.html)

Для GUI к БД советую родную [утилиту](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html#downloads)